# express.js pagination duplicated parameters when you click the page

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I have created a html page to filter some data in MongoDb and render the data to a display page. And set pagination in the display page. Whenever I choose a new page number, the URL append the page number in the pagination.

Index.js

```
  let results = await db.collection("bookings").find(whereClause,
    {
      limit: perPage,
      skip: perPage * (Math.max(req.query.page - 1, 0) || 0)
    }
    ).toArray();

  var fullUrl = req.protocol + '://' + req.get('host') + req.originalUrl;

return res.render('search', { bookings: results, pages: pages, perPage: perPage, fullUrl:fullUrl });
```

Pagination Page:

```
  <nav aria-label="Page navigation example">
    <ul class="pagination flex-wrap">
      <% for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) { %>
        <li class="page-item"></li>
          <a class="page-link" href="<%=fullUrl%>&perPage=<%=perPage%>&page=<%= i %>">
            <%= i %>
          </a>
        </li>
      <% } %>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

The problem is every time when I click a new page number in the pagination, it will append the perPage and page parameter into the original link.

http://localhost:3000/search?numTickets=1&name=somename&perPage=6&page=**5&perPage=6&page=3**

Comment: Do you have any other query parameters besides `perPage` and `page`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parse the original URL into an [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) instance. Then you can more easily manipulate the `searchParams`

```js
const fullUrl = new URL(
  `${req.protocol}://${req.get("host")}${req.originalUrl}`
);
fullUrl.searchParams.set("perPage", perPage);
fullUrl.searchParams.delete("page");

return res.render("search", {
  bookings: results,
  pages,
  fullUrl,
});
```

and in your template...

```ejs
<% for (var i = 1; i <= pages; i++) { %>
<li class="page-item">
  <a class="page-link" href="<%=fullUrl%>&amp;page=<%=i%>">
    <%= i %>
  </a>
</li>
<% } %>
```